# map click event is not being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

**Update at the bottom**

Although the map does appear, the alert inside the click function below is not appearing when I click on the map. The cursor looks like a hand, not like a pointer, by the way. The `console.log()` result does appear in the browser log.

My goal is to determine the position of the click and place a draggable marker there, but I cannot even get the listener to trigger.

The code below runs without the

```
  // == Display the map, with some controls and set the initial location 
  var start = new google.maps.LatLng({{center_lat}},{{center_lng}});
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),{
        center: start,
        zoom: {{map_zoom}},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  console.log("HERE");
  google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(){
      alert('You clicked the map.');
      });
```

I have constructed the minimal code below to demonstrate my problem. However the code only works **without** the phrase `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {}`. When that phrase is included I get the error as follows `Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined click:24 (anonymous function)`

I hope this helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
            map: map
      });

    }
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
  alert('You clicked the map.');
}); 
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong in the code you have posted (other than the `{{}}`'s which I would assume are replaced with valid values.  Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem?

Comment: No, I am not aware that I am dealing with asynchronous functions here.  I am mimicking as closely as possible the sample code at the following   [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3#events). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined` in the javascript console.

Because your map variable is not defined.  You need to initialize the click listener inside the initialize function where the map *is* defined (it is local to the initialize function).

```
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    alert('You clicked the map.');
  }); 
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtPQS/1/)

[fiddle that exhibits error](http://jsfiddle.net/dtPQS/)